# How do I convert SQL Query to Lambda?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following SQL query that returns the results I need:

```
SELECT 
       STAFF_ID
FROM [dbo].[StaffTable]
WHERE STAFF_ID NOT IN (SELECT STAFF_ID 
                                     FROM [dbo].[StaffingTable]
                                     WHERE [DATE] = @DATE
                                     AND MODEL_ID = @Model)
```

I have the following controller method to try and return the correct results:

```
public JsonResult GetStaffResults(DateTime date, string modelId)
        {
            Guid modelGuid = Guid.Parse(modelId);
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

            var staff = context.StaffTable.Select(c => new
            {
                Id = c.StaffId,
                Name = c.StaffName
            });

            var staffing = context.StaffingTable.Select(c => new
            {
                modelId = c.ModelId,
                manufacturerId = c.ManufacturerId,
                staffId = c.StaffId,
                date = c.Date,
                recordId = c.RecordId
            });

            var staffResults = staff.Where(p => staffing.Select(o => o.modelId).First() == modelGuid && !staffing.Select(o => o.date).Contains(date));

            return Json(shiftResults, settings);
        }
```

However, I'm struggling with the Lambda expression, it returns no results so I've missed something somewhere.

Comment: You don't need that `DISTINCT` in the SQL statement, it only adds a *delay* and an unnecessary sort.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll remove it, thanks.

Comment: As a side note, avoid calling the database context directly in the controller (or any final "response-sender"). Consider building a class which performs the calls independently and lets the controller consume the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 public JsonResult GetStaffResults(DateTime date, string modelId)
        {
            Guid modelGuid = Guid.Parse(modelId);
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

            var staffQuery = context.StaffTable
                .Where(s => !context
                    .StaffingTable
                    .Any(st => st.StaffId = s.StaffId && st.modelId == modelGuid && st.date == date))
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    Id = c.StaffId,
                    Name = c.StaffName
                });

            return Json(staffQuery.ToList(), settings);
        }
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. This has highlighted my need for getting better at these expressions I think!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing separate query with `Select` which has a performance issue as the queries will return `IEnumerable<T>` objects. If you want to have separate queries then try to get the query results as `IQueryable<T>` which will construct the queries and will load data at the end.

For example:

```
var query =    
    from st in context.StaffTable  
    where !(from stff in context.StaffingTable  
            select stff.CustomerID)
            where stff.MODEL_ID = ModelIdVariable AND stff.DATE = DATEVariable
           .Contains(st.CustomerID)    
    select st;
```

Declare and populate the `ModelIdVariable`  and `DATEVariable` variables before the query.

Then you can do `query.ToList<T>()` where you need the data to be loaded.